# Como pegar o penúltimo item de uma string?

Tags: mysql

Preciso pegar o penultimo nome de dentro de uma string.

Por exemplo;

> Antonio Alves Ferreira Castro

preciso do *ferreira*

Sei q para pegar o Castro eu posso utilizar o

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(NOME, ' ', -1)
```

tentei o -2, mas nao funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dessa forma:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('Antonio Alves Ferreira Castro', ' ', -2) , ' ', 1) penultimo_nome
```

Abraços.